# How to use onCreateOptionsMenu() in Activity Which Extended ListActivity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have a problem about my android app project.

I have a MainActivity which is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private NotesDataSource datasource;
    List<NoteItem> notesList;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        datasource = new NotesDataSource(this);

        refreshDisplay();
    }

    private void refreshDisplay() {
        notesList = datasource.findAll();
        ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<NoteItem>(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, notesList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

And Also I have a menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_create"
        android:title="@string/action_create"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/create_note"/>
</menu>
```

At this point the problem is starting. I have changed my superclass from **ActionBarActivity** to **ListActivity** then, when I run my app on my device, I can not see my create icon (and the top menu which include app name). What's wrong? And idea?

(Btw I am using Android Studio Ide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your theme is probably still based on `Theme.AppCompat`. If you want to use `Theme.AppCompat`, you have to inherit from `ActionBarActivity`. If you want to use `ListActivity`, you cannot use `Theme.AppCompat`.

Note that you do not need to use `ListActivity` to have a `ListView` in an activity. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat/ActionBar) demonstrating the use of `Theme.AppCompat` with an `ActionBarActivity` and a `ListView`. [Here is another sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat/ActionBarColor), the same as the previous one, except that I apply custom tints to the action bar.

Comment: Actually the theme does not matter for me. It is just simple app to learn. But when I change the superclass **ActionBarActivity** I have an error with **setListAdapter(adapter);**

Comment: @Mehmet: That is because you do not use `setListAdapter()` with `ActionBarActivity`. There is no `setListAdapter()` on `ActionBarActivity`, as you can tell by examining [the documentation to `ActionBarActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html). As I wrote in my answer, either change your theme and use `ListActivity`, or switch back to `ActionBarActivity` and deal with your `ListView` as you would any other widget.

Comment: So, should I change the theme? Because I follow a tutorial and I need to use setListAdapter()